# Firestore - Batch querying nested documents in REST API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There is a way to batch get documents after you specified exactly all the file paths using
`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectName/databases/dbName/documents:batchGet`.

And there is a way to get all documents and their fields under a collection by sending a GET to `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectName/databases/dbName/documents/collectionName`

**I ideally want to make a batch request to get document fields for all documents under an array of collections. Is there a way to do this without knowing the document names of every document I intend to get?**

*Example*

I have a structure like `projects/projectName/databases/dbName/documents/Inventory/productId/variantId/*location*`
Each productId is a document, and under this it has a collection for each variant, and within that collection are documents for each location, that contains a field `count`.

For a basket, I want to get all inventory counts for all inventory locations, for each productId/variantId in that bas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get all documents based on an array of collection names.

You can use a collection group query and search all collections of a given name, but then you must know the path of each document you want to read.

Alternatively, you can get all documents under a specific path, but then you can't filter by ID anymore, and the collections have to be under a path - not an array.

Comment: How do you mean specific path, as in a specific path to a collection ID? And assuming this extends only to the documents under this collection and not the documents within collections of documents directly under this collection?

Comment: It extends to documents in a collection group, so a group of collections all with the same name. As said: there is no way to get all documents based on an array of collection names.